# How to optimise layout without 'area' option in igraph?

Tags: layout, visualization, igraph, area

I'm trying to optimise the layout of a network I'm constructing with the following code:

```
gr <- read.table("data.txt", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
node.names <- gr[,1]
node.names <- toupper(substr(node.names, 2, nchar(node.names)))
gr <- gr[,-1]
edge.table.index <- which(gr>0.5, arr.ind=T)
d <- data.frame(first = node.names[edge.table.index[,1]], second = node.names[edge.table.index[,2]]) 
g <- graph.data.frame(d, directed=F)
g[from=V(g), to=V(g)] <- 0
layout.g <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(g, layout = layout.g, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label.cex=.7, vertex.color = "lightblue", vertex.label.family = "sans", edge.color="black", vertex.frame.color= "white")
```

In particular, what I'm trying to do is decrease the area on which the nodes are displayed such that the connected components are closer together. Previous versions of igraph had the option 'area' in the `layout.fruchterman.reingold()` function but this doesn't seem to be the case anymore. I've tried playing with various options like vertex size, vertex font size and width/height of the exported pdf file but they don't really do the trick.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Here's a link to the data file, I hope it works:
[data.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0fbJcyvGhWATmZPZnZOY1ZJU2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am having the very same question right now....